# Navigating to correct section using hamburger menu without the menu overlapping the text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a hamburger menu situation in my bootstrap application. Let me provided some context and you will require a laptop and mobile to see this. Follow the steps below:

1: On your desktop computer, visit https://www.metis-online.com

2: Scroll up and down the page and you notice the navbar is fixed, which is what I want

3: Now in the navbar, select any link like 'Courses' or 'Services'. You notice that it will take you to that relevant section and you can see the title of that section and its body.

4: Now visit the website on your mobile.

5: open the hamburger menu and navigate to the same section. You should notice the problem that event though it takes you to the right section, you can't see the title of the section because it's covered by the menu. You will need to close the menu in order to see it.

What I would like for the mobile is that when navigating to the link, you can see the top of the section without needing to close the hamburger menu, just like you can see the top of the section when you navigate through the desktop.

What will need to be changed in order for this to work?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
...
</nav>

body { 
    padding-top: 80px; 
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to shrink the <body>'s height when the hamburger is opened (so that bodyheight + hamburgerheight = windowheight), and then add margin to the top of it to make it touch the bottom? Example: when hamburger opened, change <body> styling to `{height:calc(100% - [hamburgerHeight]);overflow-y:scroll;margin-top:[hamburgerHeight];padding-top:0px;}`.

Comment: you are going to need to add extra distance scrolled upon clicking mobile menu items. e.g., add the height of the dropdown menu to the equation

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 How could you do that with `<a>`s? (Without JavaScript)

Comment: I originally thought of creating a distance through css where I did a @media and sent the padding for the body to 300px to cover the height of the hamburger menu when it's ope, but it doesn't look good at top of the page as when the menu is not open, we have this big white space. Unless if it's possible to say in javascript, if hamburger open, add padding to body, if hamburger closed, remove padding for body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I originally thought of creating a distance through css where I did a
> @media and sent the padding for the body to 300px to cover the height
> of the hamburger menu when it's open, but it doesn't look good at top
> of the page as when the menu is not open, we have this big white
> space.

The Bootstrap navbar will start to introduce the hamburger & dropdown layout starting at `991px`. Like the implementation you are proposing, it is possible to add the classes (with padding properties for example like you mentioned) to the relevant elements that would produce the output of "pushing down" the content such that it is visible when the dropdown is open.

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
   ...
}
```

For the JavaScript side, you can refer to this [Documentation about the Bootstrap Collapse event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/collapse/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#navbarSupportedContent').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    // code some necessary logic... add your classes here
    console.log('navbar opening');
  })

  $('#navbarSupportedContent').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    // code some necessary logic... remove your classes here
    console.log('navbar closing');
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

While this is an approach the can "solve" your issue. I do not recommend it from a UX perspective. I have encountered a similar issue on a SPA website I created. It looked a lot better if I collapsed the navbar dropdown when some routing occured. This enabled the user to see the entire page properly instead of keeping it open. For this, simply add/remove the class `show` on the `navbar-collapse` element

[image]